# How to read minimum and maximum pixel values of an image in earth engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, reducers

I want to read the minimum and maximum rainfall value for my study region. While using the `reducer` function **I can read the mean value, however, *for min and max value* it is showing *null***. I wish to extract the min and max value to control the color bar/ palette limit. How to read the min and max values.
Below is my script,

```
Map.addLayer(Tawi, visParams, nameLayer, shown, opacity); /Tawi is the name of shapefile
Map.centerObject(Tawi);

var ChirpsDataset = ee.ImageCollection('UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY');
var Chirps = ChirpsDataset.filterDate('2018-07-14', '2019-07-30').sum().clip(Tawi);
                     
print(Chirps, 'Precipitation');
var precip = Chirps.select('precipitation');

var meanValue = Chirps.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry: Tawi.geometry(),
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  crsTransform: [1,0,0,0,1,0],
  maxPixels: 1e9
});    
print('Mean precipitation:', meanValue)

var maxValue = Chirps.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  geometry: Tawi.geometry(),
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  crsTransform: [1,0,0,0,1,0],
  maxPixels: 1e9
});    
print('Max precipitation:', maxValue)
```

Here is the [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/38fea20ead82be90c66d8829dfa86621) to script.

Comment: Please add a link to the script and share your assets: 'getLink` button in the top right of the map.

Comment: I have added the link in the edit.
https://code.earthengine.google.com/38fea20ead82be90c66d8829dfa86621

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd probably best define an appropriate scale for your analysis. Read about scale [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/scale). The composite image of you has `crsTransform: [1,0,0,0,1,0]`, which gives a scale of 111319m:

```
print(precip.projection().nominalScale())
```

Probably, you want to run the computation on the scale of the imagery. It depends on where you are on the world, but approx 5km should fit well for your area. Thus, a better idea would be defining the scale (in meters), for example:

```
var maxValue = Chirps.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  geometry: Tawi.geometry(),
  scale: 5000,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});    
print('Max precipitation:', maxValue)
```

Comment: It worked, however, I have one more query, is their any way to read that scale of 5000 m from the image itself. This would be better as different images will have different scale e.g., Landsat or Sentinel.